# Update a field 'version' into a table

Tags: c#, oracle

I have this situation:

I have two tables:

- Table A
- Staging_Table A

Both tables contain those common columns:

- Code
- Description

Into Table A I also have a column `Version` which identifies the last version of corresponding column `Code`.

My problem is how to update the column `Version` once a new `Description` is stored for the same `Code` (I fill up the `Staging_Table` with a bulk Insert from C#. I have a flow of data that change once a week).

I need to insert the new row  into Table A which contain the same `Code`, but a different `Description`, without deleting the old one.

I insert the rows from Staging table to table A with MINUS operation and I have this mechanism within a stored procedure because I also fill up the staging table with a Bulk Insert from C#.

The result I need to obtain is the following:

TABLE A:

```
Id  Code Description   Version  End_date
--  -----------------  -------  --------
 1  8585 Red Car             1  26-mag-2015
 2  8585 Red Car RRRR        2  01-giu-2015
```

How can I do that?

I hope the issue is clear

Comment: This seems like a good candidate for a MERGE statement. What is the Id column and where does it come from? Is it in the staging table, is it a sequence? First you said there are columns Code and Description, then you talked about Version, and in the "result" you show more columns, Id and End_date. (By the same token: what is End_date and where does it come from?)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly process work like that:
1. Data is loaded to staging table Staging_table_A
2. Data is inserted from Staging_table_A itno Table_A with additional column version.

I would do:

```
with cnt as (select count(*) c, code from Table_A group by code)
Insert into Table_A (select sta.*, nvl(cnt.c,0) + 1 as version 
from Staging_table_A sta left outer join cnt on (sta.code = cnt.code));
```

This is based on condition that in Table_A versions contains no duplicates.

Comment: I would go with `MAX(version)` rather than `COUNT(*)` in the sub-query because it's safer. Rows aren't deleted as part of the loading process now but they may be deleted by a subsequent step or a future change of policy e.g archiving old versions.

Comment: You're right max is much better than count in that case.

Comment: You perfectly understood the process. I will try whit this solution. But, in order to take MAX (Version) I have to take the code which perfectly match with the new description. I don't know how to do that because I have a lots of data. I can't put it in a simple variable.

Comment: I also have to check if the description has changed or not